# Как мне получить доступ к значениям компонента angular из контекста функции window?

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-history-api

Я отлавливаю нажатие кнопки "Обратно" в браузере- после чего должны подгрузиться данные, соответственно текущим запросам роутинга, но там идёт потеря контекста, на сколько я понял, и я не могу вызвать функции самого компонента Angular.
Я делаю так.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.my_func();

    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      console.log(this);
      this.my_func();  //идёт потеря контекста, а мне нужно запустить эту функцию
    };
  }
```

Comment: заменить на стрелочную функцию?

Comment: @"Dmitrii Sedov" . Подскажите, как именно? ()=>{ }

Comment: window.onpopstate = (event) => {...все остальное}

Comment: @"Dmitrii Sedov" спасибо большое!

Comment: А вообще, вы не правильно используете подписи на событие. Надо использовать `@HostListener`. Погуглите!

Comment: @"Stepan Kasyanenko"  Я так сделал, но в обеих случаях почему-то функция сразабывает 2 раза, а при следующих нажатиях кнопки назад- ещё +1 раз @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event) {
    this.startDownloading();
  }

Comment: Я голову сломал, что там происходит каждый раз при нажатии и почему функции выполняются много раз после нажатия кнопки,как буд-то что-то не уничтожается и висит дальше. @"Dmitrii Sedov"